# Rj45 continuity results

Tags: wiring, ethernet, network

I bought a rj45 tester to test the continuity on 2 different rj45 ports at my house. Every other ports are working correctly but those 2 are not.
Look at the result:
[image: the result is weird]

Normally the possible results are that:
[image: the possible results]

Does somebody understand what’s going on ? Please help me! I already tried to setup everything from scratch again and it didn’t help. I can’t understand why those 2 rj45 are not working. It’s exactly the same setup everywhere :(

Comment: Those aren't all the possible results, just some examples. In this case the location is miswired. Not all possible miswirings are shown on that graphic.

Comment: I notice that one of the examples is mis-captioned. The second example is captioned as "Pin12, Pin45 are both shorted" but it probably should say "Pins 5 and 8 are open."

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Chris O's excellent answer, there is one other thing to consider:

**There may be other connections involved.**

A typical example is if two RJ45 jacks are patched together through a patch panel in a central location. If the two ends in the rooms are wired identically (e.g., T568B) but one (or both) of the connections to the patch panel is not wired the same way then you can get some very strange results.

It is *possible*, though less likely, that you could have a cable-to-cable patch somewhere, which would be generally unreliable and not recommended. But *anything* is possible in the wonderful world of low-voltage cabling. (In the wonderful world of mains cabling (120V/240V power) there are wacky things too - the difference is that with low voltage the wacky stuff won't work but it won't kill you or start a fire.)

Comment: +1 This is absolutely true - especially in the case of a room-to-room connection rather than room-to-patch panel.

Answer (score 5):

Did you install the jacks or did a previous owner/tenant?

What the cable tester is showing is that one of the jacks in the pair you are testing is wired incorrectly.  You will need to pull both jacks and check their wiring.

**Ethernet Standards**

There are multiple cabling standards for telecom jacks and they have changed over time.  Modern wiring using 8-pin 8-conductor jacks and 4-pair wiring (commonly referred to as Category 5, 5e, 6, 7, etc.) allows you to use the jacks for Ethernet.

The two standards for wiring Ethernet jacks are EIA-T-568A and 568B.  People will argue that one is better than the other but to be completely honest, it doesn't matter which one you go with in your home, except that everything needs to be the same.

[image: Cable wiring schemes]

See the back of the jack here:

[image: Back of a keystone RJ-45 Jack]

If you look closely, you'll see the A and B noting which colors to use in which position.

**Don't forget the testing equipment**

The wiring of the patch cables that you use to connect both ends of the tester matter as well.  Make sure they are both straight-through cables (i.e. wired the same at both ends) and that you use the same ones in every test or your results will be worthless.

Answer (score 3):

inspect the wiring at both ends and correct the one that's wrong.